# Composer fail to require symfony/symfony on symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony4

I have installed the last version of symfony through composer with the following line:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton whatever
```

Then following the instructions on this [page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/using_components.html#using-all-of-the-components) i decided to require the whole framework so i have not to install all the bundles one by one by entering this:

```
composer require symfony/symfony
```

But the problem is that i end up with the following error:

```
composer require symfony/symfony
Using version ^4.0 for symfony/symfony
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/symfony v4.0.0 conflicts with __root__[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
    - symfony/symfony v4.0.1 conflicts with __root__[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
    - symfony/symfony v4.0.2 conflicts with __root__[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
    - Installation request for __root__ No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) -> satisfiable by __root__[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony ^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

When i specify the version **4.0.2** i have 2 errors less, but the problem remain the same:

```
composer require symfony/symfony v4.0.2
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for __root__ No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) -> satisfiable by __root__[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
    - symfony/symfony v4.0.2 conflicts with __root__[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony v4.0.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v4.0.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

My composer.json:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "sensiolabs/security-checker": "^4.1",
        "symfony/console": "^4.0",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install --symlink --relative %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "security-checker security:check": "script"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "id": "0133333333333333337ed17ed",
            "allow-contrib": false
        }
    }
}
```

I'm very confused, i can't find much informations about this on the symfony doc, and i'm far from being good with composer, any clue?

Comment: What about the `conflict` section of your `composer.json` containing `symfony/symfony` ? That explicitly tells composer not to install your package and `symfony/symfony` together.

Comment: @ccKep indeed so i must misunderstand something, because im following the intructions as stated on the doc.

Comment: Which step told you / caused the `conflict` section to appear? The part you linked shouldn't - try removing it to see if you have any luck `require`ing `symfony/symfony` then.

Comment: For the record, the installation worked, but symfony has become a mess, for instance the front controller has gone missing

Comment: Even if get this to work it won't do what you want.  symfony/symfony is intended to install all of symfony components.  It won't install bundles which means they won't be integrated into the framework.  Just start over with symfony/skelton and then require the recipes as needed.  Or stick with 3.4 and use the standard framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `symfony/skeleton` package is designed to be used with [Symfony Flex](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html). The entire point of that project is to *avoid* using the entire framework, so the package expressly conflicts with it.

You should either be creating your project from `symfony/framework-standard-edition`, which will pull in the entire framework, or make use of the new functionality in Flex to pull in just the components or ["recipes"](https://symfony.sh/) that you need.

Comment: When i enter the following command `composer create-project symfony/symfony-standard whatever` after a short while a get an InvalidArgumentException : Could not find package 'symfony/symfony-standard' with stability stable.

Comment: Sorry, that was the Github address. The command you want is `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition`

Comment: Just be aware that you will get 3.4.  As far as I can tell, there is no standard edition for 4.0.